# How do I convert RGB indexes under luminance condition L (from photometry) to a perceptually scaled equivalent (e.g. CIECAM02)?

Tags: perception, experimental-psychology, color

I would like to determine the similarity of a set of RGB colors that are displayed on a monitor using CIECAM02 (or CIEDE2000). I have access to a photometer. How do I go about this?

The goal is uniform lightness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question on computer sciences. Perhaps Stack Overflow or Photography would be better candidates, but not CogSci